# MFA Client for Microsoft Graph without AAD Registration

Tags: javascript, c#, azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

Using a simple C#/WPF application and the SharePointPnPCoreOnline I can call the GetWebLoginClientContext() method which opens up a window for the user to authenticate via MFA to a given SharePoint site.  From that point on I can query the SP site based on the users level of access.  The convenient thing about this approach is that I don't have to register my WPF application with Azure AD, give it permissions, get a client ID, client secret, yadda yadda yadda.

Is there a library that will similarly allow me to authenticate a user via MFA so that I can access the Graph API based on their permissions without the AAD app registration requirement from a C# client application?  How about a JavaScript application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible, to access the graph api, (for a work or student account) there must be an app registration to give you permissions to those endpoints. even the "graph explorer" has a registered application.

Even with your sharepointpnpcoreonline, that likely authenticates against an app registration/service principal, its just that its microsoft trusted app registrations, so it's hiding it in the background from you. if you were to check in your azure ad enterprise applications under microsoft applications, there are various service principals for sharepoint online for example.

Long and short of it is that you need to have an app registration/service principal to access graph api endpoints. you don't necessarily need a client secret though, as that depends on your specific application and the authentication flow you choose to use in your app registration.

Comment: So it sounds like my only hope here (to avoid app registration) is if Microsoft has a library for Graph API that has a trusted app registration baked into it.  Anyone know of any?